# plus former item in a list of file in time format in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have  a file, each line contain video time length getting from ffmpeg, how to plus former items to construct a new list .tried in py2.7  timedelta got me confused

```
00:00:02.34
00:00:04.57
00:00:04.40
00:00:01.37
```

expected output

```
00:00:02.34
00:00:06.81# 00:00:02.34+00:00:04.57
00:00:02.34+00:00:04.57+00:00:04.40
00:00:02.34+00:00:04.57+00:00:04.40+00:00:01.37
```

at last  srt subtitle time can generated

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:11,310


2
00:00:11,310 --> 00:00:15,050
```

Comment: You could use `itertools.accumulate`

Comment: @Jab: looks like `accumulate` is not available for Python 2.7?

Comment: If the times are in a fixed format above, you could split up the elements with `split()` and make a function to add 2 of the values appropriately, and use that to create items for your running total.

Comment: what do you mean by spilt

Comment: final solution 
```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import itertools
import pandas as pd

with open('timeline.txt') as f:
    out = []
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip())
        out.append(pd.to_timedelta(line.strip()))
    out = list(itertools.accumulate(out))
    print(out)
```